# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus regularity needed

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $f$ is integrable on $[0,\infty)$ and that $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$.

For $x\geq 0$, define $$g(x)=\int_0^\infty f(x+r) dr.$$ Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, if $f'$ exists and is integrable on $[0,\infty)$, then I can justify:
$$g'(u)=\int_0^\infty f'(u+r)dr=\int_0^\infty\partial_r[f(u+r)]\,dr=[f(u+r)]_{r=0}^\infty=-f(u).$$

However the conclusion that ``$g'(u)=-f(u)$" does not require any derivatives on $f$. Can I say $g$ is more regular than $f$ in this way?

Comment: Continuity of $f$ is sufficient. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}h=-\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int^{x+h}_xf}h=-f(x)$. The hypothesis $\lim_\infty f=0$ is not needed either.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Generalizations : if $f$ is not continuous, $g'=-f$ will still hold *almost everywhere*. Note also that $g(x)=C-\int_0^xf$, so that you don't need to consider indefinite integrals.